# I can't find the components to add to main.storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, xcode13

I am using Xcode Version 13.4 (13F17a), I am trying to learn iOS development with UIKit but I am unable to find the elements to add to storyboard(ie button, textField) which force me to design programmatically like

`

```
class ButtonDesign:UIButton{
    func buttonUiDesign() -> UIButton{
        let buttonX = 150
        let buttonY = 150
        let buttonHeight = 50
        let buttonWidth = 100
        
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Click me!!", for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = .blue
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        
        button.frame = CGRect(x: buttonX, y: buttonY, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
        
        return button
        
    }
    
    //Notification Using Haptic Engine when clicked.
    @objc func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton){
//        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "clicked", message: "you have clicked the button", preferredStyle: .alert)
//        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion:nil)
        
        let impact = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator()
        impact.impactOccurred()
        
    }
```

Below is the picture of the main.storyboard can someone please educate me. I want to drag and drop the elements that am choosing to viewcontroler. I am apologize for my English, am using google translator.Below is my main.storyboard [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu3ZZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click to the plus symbol on the top right conner of the IDE
[image]

Comment: Thanks, You have saved me a lot of time, God bless you.